# How can I take actions and states when my transition between states depends on multiple actions simultaneously?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I have a model whose states depend on multiple actions; I can take a single parameter as action, but what if the state transition depends on more than one action?

Comment: This is rather vague! Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reinforcement learning techniques, such as [Q-Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning), each state change is probabilistic and depends on one action. This is used to estimate the expected reward (such as the Q-value: *Q(s,a)* in Q-Learning).

If you do not have a large number of actions, you could define combinations of actions that can occur together as new actions; e.g. if you have actions *a<sub>1</sub>* and *a<sub>2</sub>* you could make an action *a<sub>3</sub>* that applies the effects of both actions at the same time.
Another idea is to define some kind of action hierarchy in which higher.

You should also have a look at several scientific works in which they use multiple actions to do state transitions, as commented in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/9z8tok/d_reinforcement_learning_with_multiple/).